# Batch file for loop not working when passing filename variable with spaces although delims is specified

Tags: batch-file

This is my first time working with batch files, so sorry if this is something simple I just missed.

I have a batch file, to which I need to pass a file path/name.  This path has spaces.  So as far as I know, to pass it in I need quotes around it.  Once I get it in the batch file then I need to run it through a for loop, but it always gives me an error that is splitting the file path at the spaces.  I am using the "delims=" in the loop.  Here are some of the things I've tried, none of which have worked:

just passing in the parameter into the loop (echo %1 comes out with the file path in quotes)

```
for /f "usebackq skip=4 delims=" %%a in (%1) do ( stuff )
```

causes: 'Suite' is not recognized as an internal or external command (Suite is the word after the first space)

passing the parameter surrounded by quotes (echo "%1" produces file path surrounded by two quotes)

```
for /f "usebackq skip=4 delims=" %%a in ("%1") do ( stuff )
```

causes: The system cannot find the file "G:\Programming\App" (stuff before 1st space)

getting rid of the quotes and passing in variable in quotes (echo "%fn%" produces file path in quotes again)

```
set fn=%1
set fn=%fn:"=%
    for /f "usebackq skip=4 delims=" %%a in ("%fn%") do ( stuff )
```

causes: 'Suite' is not recognized as an internal or external command

getting rid of the quotes and passing in the variable without quotes (echo %fn% produces full file path with no quotes)

```
set fn=%1
set fn=%fn:"=%
    for /f "usebackq skip=4 delims=" %%a in (%fn%) do ( stuff )
```

causes: The system cannot find the file Suite.

The stuff portion works if I just type in a file path in quotes so I don't think that part is causing problems.  I think the problems are occurring before it gets there.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT

The batch file is being called by another batch file with a path embedded that loops through the files in that path:

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    for %%a in ("G:\Programming\App Suite 2.0\IT Regional Files\Phone Logs\*.log") do (

        call ..\BatchFile\split.bat "%%~fa" 
            )




    endlocal
```

Also did try with "%~1" and it produced the same results as %1.

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58453606/edit) to show us the command your using to run the batch file and an example of the possible input parameters you're passing to it. _So far I can see `"G:\Programming\App Suite"`_. An overview of what you're wanting to do with that input once in the script would probably help us too.

Comment: What happens when you just use `for /f "usebackq skip=4 delims=" %%a in ("%~1") do ( stuff )`? Given the provided information, that should do stuff based upon the line content of each log file passed to it beginning from line `5`. Is that what you intend it to do?

Comment: I suggest opening a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/) and run `for %I in ("G:\Programming\App Suite 2.0\IT Regional Files\Phone Logs\*.log") do @echo %I`. You see that `for` assigns to loop variable `I` name of found log file with full path without `"`. Delayed expansion should be enabled only on really needed as otherwise the `for` loop would not process correct file names with `!` in name. So all you need in the other batch file below `@echo off` is: `for %%I in ("G:\Programming\App Suite 2.0\IT Regional Files\Phone Logs\*.log") do call "%~dp0..\BatchFile\split.bat" "%%I"`.

Comment: Run in cmd window `call /?` for an explanation on how to reference batch file arguments. `%1` references argument 1 as passed to the batch file which means without or with `"` depending on how the first argument string was specified on command line starting the batch file. `%~1` references first argument string with surrounding `"` removed if there are surrounding `"` at all. So using `"%~1"` results in referencing first argument string always enclosed in `"` independent on first argument string passed to the batch file without or with `"` as required on using `for` with `/F` and `usebackq`.